# JavaScript : validation in input type ( Telephone NO )

Tags: javascript, regex

I have input type like :-

```
<input type="number" name="rtb-phone" id="rtb-phone" value="">
```

Now i need to do the validation in this input that cannot add number above 10 digit, and we must add first (05)...

So, we must add telephone NO like (0511111111).

any telephone not same 10 digit ,, and start with 05, we need to print error ,,,

How can do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel)
HTML

```
   <form>
      <div>
        <label for="telNo">Enter a telephone number (in the form 05-xxxx-xxxx): </label>
        <input id="telNo" name="telNo" type="tel" required
               pattern="[05]{2}[0-9]{8}">
        <span class="validity"></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="number"] {
  width: 100px;
}

input + span {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

input:invalid+span:after {
  position: absolute; content: '✖';
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #8b0000;
}

input:valid+span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '✓';
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #009000;
}
```

Comment: Your regex `[05]{2}[0-9]{8}` will also match 0011111111. Try to add some explanation of your code for the OP and future readers.

Comment: mmm,, but the type="tel" its accept enter (abcdfg ....) ... its must not add (abcdfg ....)

Comment: mmm i try 0011111111 and accepted!! its must not accept!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" name="rtb-phone" id="rtb-phone" value="" pattern="/[\0][\5]\d{8}/">
```

Try this

Comment: ,, its not work ,, i try add 05963963 , and the form was add and accept it !!

Comment: Why the `\0` between square brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

[`^05\d{8}$`](https://regex101.com/r/YZ6iKS/1)

The regex matches from the beginning of the string `^` 05 and then 8 digits `\d{8}` until the end of the string `$`.

You are using a phonenumber so you might use `type="tel"` or `type="text"` and add the `required` attribute.

```html
<form>
  <input type="tel" name="rtb-phone" id="rtb-phone" value="" pattern="^05\d{8}$" required>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click">
</form>
```